# How do I do an Active login into windows Azure ACS

Tags: azure, access-token, wif, acs

I have an Azure ACS set up.  I have several IP's configured; one of which is a custom STS.  The "passive" scenario - in which browser redirects are used to get the token from the ip to acs and back again to my RP - works like a charm.
In the passive scenario it is possible to use the homerealm to "guide" the ACS towards the IP-STS of my choice.
I am wondering now whether something similar is possible in the active scenario.  More specifically : can I retrieve a token from ACS by providing a username and a password (and some id of the IP that will handle the user-name password) to ACS.

(I want to keep knowledge about the custom STS out of my clients so I'm not asking the custom STS for a token *directly*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it.  I need a two-way process.  First request a token on the custom sts using a username and password (with audience set to the correct endpoint of the acs sts).  Next "exchange" this token for a token issued by the ACS as in : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675217/exchange-ip-sts-jwt-token-for-acs-jwt-toke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675217/exchange-ip-sts-jwt-token-for-acs-jwt-token)n

Answer (score 0):

The active authentication flow doesn't work exactly that way. The credentials don't go to ACS, but to the IdP directly via a protocol like WS-Trust. For an example of this, take a look at the [ACS Federated Authentication sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127796.aspx).

None of the protocols that ACS supports allow the credentials to be ferried through a federation provider in the way you suggest directly (doing so would create an unnecessary security issue as those credentials would be exposed to the FP), but the fact that these creds go to the IdP instead of ACS should be invisible to the end-user.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand.  I feared something like that.  
I do remember seeing an example where the scenario I describe works.  The difference in the example was that the "credentials" where the windows Kerberos data, which were passed to the accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9 endpoint through some "wrap" properties.  So I was wondering if it could be made to work for username/password.
(I still feel that ACS lacks something similar to v2/metadata/identityProviders.js to get the endpoints for the active scenario.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'll explain the source of my confusion.  If found some examples that login to the ACS Management Console using a username and a password.  This is quite different from using the ACS to get a token for a replying party.  The examples I'm talking about let you manipulate the "objects" inside the ACS management user interface using an OData protocol (https://<yourNameSpace>.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/mgmt/service), while what I want is a token for a replying party.